# How to make scrolling counter in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like to create a scrolling counter and I'm wondering on how to implement this in flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wanted to do this in a project, so I create an implicit animation widget, called `AnimatedFlipCounter`, that achieves similar effect.

I have published it as a package: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_flip_counter

**Usage:**

```
AnimatedFlipCounter(
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
   value: _value, /* pass in a number like 2014 */
)
```

[image: AnimatedFlipCounter demo]

**Decimals:**

```
AnimatedFlipCounter(
  value: _value,
  fractionDigits: 2, // decimal precision
  suffix: "%",
  textStyle: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 40,
      color: _value >= 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
  ),
)
```

[image: Decimal demo]

Comment: great but how to implement a double value? + i have interest to contribute to this project can you provide to project link?

Comment: @ElMobark Thanks for your suggestion. I have updated it with decimal support, and published it to pub, please see the link in the updated answer.

Comment: Hello again, I'm really amazed by your work , anyway I'm working on a Flutter library that makes splash screen like twitter do in iOS I will be very grateful if I benefit from your amazing skills, what do you think? Can we participate?

Answer (score 1):

You should be implement below ways

```
class ValueChangeAnimationWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ValueChangeAnimationWidgetState createState() =>
      ValueChangeAnimationWidgetState();
}

class ValueChangeAnimationWidgetState
    extends State<ValueChangeAnimationWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), vsync: this);
    final Animation curve =
    CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeOut);
    animation = IntTween(begin: 0, end: 10).animate(curve)
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.reverse();
        }
        if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    controller.forward();
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Scaffold(
              body: new Center(
                child: Text(animation.value.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48.0)),
              ));
        });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: This merely changes the text from 0 to 10, but does not have the scroll animation.

Comment: The argument type 'Animation<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Animation<double>'

Answer (score 0):

i use tween animation with animation builder

```
IntTween(begin: 0, end: starredCount).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @murat. Can you please explain in brief. I'm not getting your answer.

Comment: @Murat Aslan please provide proper codes to run it.

Comment: @RaviDhorajiya I tried to figure out his snippet, but the results are not as expected, anyhow I leave it here: 

return TweenAnimationBuilder<int>(
      tween: IntTween(begin: 0, end: 1500),
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
      builder: (BuildContext context, int val, _) {
        return Text('$val');
      },
    );